# A tool bar that reloads the tableview when a toolbar button is pressed

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitoolbar

I'm trying to create a single class and xib where a tableview can be reloaded with different core entities depending on which toolbar button you press. I've got my code working and can see it loading the different entities in my fetchedResultsController. however when I message [self.tableView reloaddata] my table view delegates are never called. Does anyone know of an example where I could do this with out resorting to having 4 different viewcontrollers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Is the delegate of the tableView set ? Can you show us the code please ?

2- You can use 4 different tableViews and hide/show them when you press the toolbar button.

But I think the first solution is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing I'm learning about iphone development is if your trying to do something that's difficult you're probably going about it the wrong way. After initially thinking I didn't want to use a tab controller and four views it looks like that's what I should really do. I thought it would be easier to keep all the code in one class file, but quickly that gets out of hand. Better to have 4 view controllers and load as needed